# Consider the famous thought experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, probability, thought-experiment

If we consider two people A and B who both are conducting the famous Schroedinger's Cat Experiment. Person A tries to open the box to see if the cat is alive or dead, Chances of Cat's death are 50-50 obviously. If A observes that the cat is alive (let's assume) then does that affect probability for B who haven't seen the box yet. Now consider that the person A tells that the cat is alive, now does the probability of B still same or it change now? In either of the cases, if the probability remains same doesn't that mean that past could be changed.

Comment: This may help. It explains Schrodinger's cat and another way to think about it. [Parallel Worlds Probably Exist. Here’s Why](https://www.veritasium.com/videos/2020/3/6/parallel-worlds-probably-exist-heres-why)

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing collapse of the wavefunction with lack of knowledge. Like Young Kindaichi said, unless your states evolve in time, B will see the same exact result obtained by A.

You can think of this as a machine rolling a dice inside of a box without your looking at the outcome. Then you open the box and see it's 4. After some time B comes and opens the same exact box and of course he will observe 4.

You might think this is like a classical trick but it's not. If you had a radioactive material inside of your box and you observed it "decayed", there's no chance B will observe it "not yet decayed".

Answer (score 0):

No, Once A takes the measurement, that means the state has collapsed and If B takes the same measurement, He will found the same result. (Not considering any evolution of state)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have re-invented the [Wigner’s Friend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%27s_friend) thought experiment, on which there has been much discussion and debate. But while it says that person A and person B can’t agree on the quantum states involved, they will always agree on the results of measurements.